# Explain the following doubts please

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-programming

Below is the implementation of this SPOJ problem: www.spoj.com/problems/ACODE/

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char str[5002];

int main() {
   scanf("%s",str);
   while(str[0]!='0')
   {
      int len=strlen(str);
      long long dp[len+1]={0};
      /*base case*/
      dp[0]=1;
      int i=1; //i for index
      while(i<len)
      {

         int num=(str[i-1]-'0')*10;
         num+=str[i]-'0';

         /*checking for valid 1 digit number*/
         if(str[i]-'0') //Why minus '0'*10
         {
            dp[i]=dp[i-1];
         }  
         /*checking for two digit number*/
         if(num>9 && num<=26)   
         {
            dp[i]+=dp[i-2<0?0:i-2];  //How does this work?
         }

         i++;   
      }
      printf("%lld\n",dp[len-1]);
      scanf("%s",str);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Following are the things I didn't understand:-
why is dp initialized to 0?
why do we subtract '0'*10?
and **how does the part of dp[i-1] and dp[i-2] work**?

Comment: Is this C++ code? And did you write it, or is it someone else's submission, since you don't understand it?

Comment: Explain this **line** of code? That's a whole page of code! ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane - Note: `using namespace std;`

Comment: @BobJarvis indeed that's why I commented (along with `#include <bits/stdc++.h>)`

Comment: Ah - just noted that it was tagged as `c`. Fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is dp initialized to 0?

for using for example addition operation `dp[i]+=dp[i-2<0?0:i-2];` you should use a valid value not a  random value

> why do we subtract '0'*10?

for conversion of char to int you substarct the ascii of '0' (0x30) for example `'1' /* 0x31 */ - '0' /* 0x30 */ = 1`

> and how does the part of dp[i-1] & dp[i-2] work? (`dp[i]+=dp[i-2<0?0:i-2];`)

this instruction is equivalent:

```
if (i-2<0)
    dp[i]+=dp[0];
else
    dp[i]+=dp[i-2];
```

Comment: You didn't understand third part . OP is not talking about `&` operator , but the part which incorporated them both in expression .

Comment: I mean why do we use dp[i-2] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int num=(str[i-1]-'0')*10;
```

In this it *convert character to integer*. Lets say `str[i-1]` has character `'2'` , so `'2'-'0'` would result into `2` , and then multiply by `10` .

So `num` will have value `2*10=20` as according to example.

```
dp[i]+=dp[i-2<0?0:i-2];  //How does this work?
```

In this what it does is add integer at index `i` in array `dp` plus the integer at index calculated in expression .

The expression(*which is using ternary operator*) `i-2<0?0:i-2` will evaluate as if `i-2` is less than `0` then value will be `0` and if not then value will be `i-2`.

Answer (score 0):

**why is dp initialized to 0**

long long dp[len+1]={0};

Above line will initialize complete array with 0 .

**why do we subtract '0'**

Statement `str[i-1]` will return the character value , to convert character to integer , we must subtract it from '0'(ASCII value is 48).

**how does the part of dp[i-1] and dp[i-2] work?**
Thats the way to access array element through indexes .

Answer (score 0):

This is just an if clause in one line.

```
dp[i-2<0?0:i-2]

same as

if((i-2) < 0) 
 dp[0]; 
else
 dp[i-2];
```